# Who makes the Code of Conduct?

Tags: discussion

Who are the decision makers of what needs to be in the [Code of Conduct](https://law.stackexchange.com/conduct)?

Site owners? Moderators? Voters?

For example, I would strongly oppose the guideline "Avoid sarcasm". Is there a way to influence the Code of Conduct in that direction?

Comment: It might depend what kind of sarcasm you are thinking about. The other day, on a MetaStackoverflow question, someone answered with a point of view, and someone else mocked the answer with a very strong sarcastic tone (I mean, it was clearly an attack). That might be the kind of sarcasm we should be avoiding.

Comment: @Clockwork It might indeed. My biggest concern though is the word "avoid". Imagine if the law was saying "avoid murdering people" instead of "do not do it". This just creates too much room for moderators' discretion and impartiality. Sarcasm should be either allowed or not full stop.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Code of Conduct is made by the site owners and applies to all sites in the network (it's just hosted in different places). It has seen a couple of iterations so far, and they do request feedback from the community on Meta Stack Exchange:

- [The NEW new "Be Nice" Policy ("Code of Conduct") — Updated with your feedback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240839/295232)
- [We'd like your feedback on our new Code of Conduct!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312038/295232)
- [The second draft of our Code of Conduct is available for feedback and review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312850/295232)

Sarcasm can be a great tool when properly used. The main problem, especially in written form, is that it's often hard to distinguish from unfriendly language or worse. For many users here (including me) English is not their first language, and being from different cultures may influence people's understanding of or reaction to sarcasm. Therefore, the Code of Conduct advises against using it.

Comment: Thanks. However, what puzzles me is that this answer refers to SE-general Code of Conduct discussions, not specifically Law SE. Are the Codes of Conduct all the same for all SE sites? If so, why have a Code of Conduct addressed under law.stackexchange.com ? If not so, are there discussions specifically re Law SE Code of Conduct?

Comment: It's a network-wide policy.

Comment: One easy way to make it obvious any sarcasm is intended jokingly would be to add a `:p` or `:D`

Comment: Sarcasm does not translate well between different languages and often beween dialects of one language.